# How can I exclude strings containing numbers with Regex?

Tags: python, regex

Here is my current code:

```
import re
start_line = 163
with open('file.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()[start_line:]
  lines = '\n'.join(lines)
words = re.findall(r'\$\w+', lines)
```

Which creates a list like this:

```
[‘$ALPP’, ‘$ABML’, ‘$700’, ‘$15M’]
```

How can I also use regex to exclude any strings that contain digits?

Comment: Is it necassary to use regex?

Comment: @BuddyBob yes, because I'm trying to learn Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```py
import re
start_line = 163
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[start_line:]
    lines = '\n'.join(lines)
    words = re.findall(r'\$[a-zA-Z_]+', lines)
```

Note that this will exclude words with non-alphabetic punctuation in them too, such as `it's`, `man-eating`, or `start_line`, as well as any words that may have punctuation attached, such as a `word.` at the end of a sentence. If that might matter for your data, just add any characters you want to include inside the `[...]`.

**Edit:** address comments.

Comment: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Answer (score 3):

\w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_], so it includes numbers. Try something like \D (any non-digit) instead.

Hint: use a website like https://regex101.com/ to test your regexes, read descriptions and get visual feedback as you go.

Comment: as @WiktorStribiżew stated, `\w` is not equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` by default. [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information

Comment: posting links as answer without much description is against the rules

Comment: as far as I know, this rule only applies to answers, not comments. By the way, I provided context by pointing out that it is not the default behavior, and more can be read in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

When using ascii strings, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

So you could use `[a-zA-Z_]` instead.

Comment: In Python, `\w` is not equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` by default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are correct, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\B\$[A-Za-z_]+\b', lines)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/kXgCty/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                           or two non-word chars (\W)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z_]+               any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '_' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```